# Column 'id' not found While calling stored procedure in HIbernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures, hibernate-criteria

I have created one stored procedure in Mysql and I am trying to call that stored procedure using J2EE/ Hibernate. While executing stored procedure its showing me error.

> Hibernate: call getUserData(?,?)
>   Mar 04, 2018 12:06:18 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
>
> Mar 04, 2018 12:06:18 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions 
>   ERROR: Column 'id' not found.
>
> Error occured while executing SP : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

I have not mentioned **id** in my stored procedure still it is showing me error regarding **id**.

> **User.java**

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
}
```

> **UserDao.java**

```
public List<User> searchUserListWithSP(String firstName,String lastName) {

    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("call getUserData(:firstName,:lastName)")      
                .addEntity(User.class)
                .setParameter("firstName", firstName)
                .setParameter("lastName", lastName);

        userList = query.list();

        System.out.println(userList);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error occured while executing SP : "+e);
    }
    System.out.println("UserDao @searchUserListWithSP -- END");
    return userList;
}
```

> **getUserData.sql (Stored Procedure)**

```
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists getUserData//
create procedure getUserData(
in firstName varchar(50),
in lastName varchar(50)
)
begin

declare queryString text default "";

set queryString = concat(queryString, 'select u.firstName, u.lastName from user u where 1=1');

if (firstName is not null and firstName != '') then
    set queryString = concat(queryString," and firstName like '%", firstName,"%' ");
end if;

if (lastName is not null and lastName != '') then
    set queryString = concat(queryString," and lastName like '%", lastName,"%' ");
end if;

set queryString = concat(queryString, ";");

-- select queryString;
SET @SQL := queryString;
prepare stmt from @SQL;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

end//
```

So while executing store procedure from UserDao I am getting this error. I have searched for it but haven't found anything specific. If I am adding id in my stored procedure select statement then it will resolve issue but then it is showing error for other fields.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this it will be helpful to understand concepts of addEntity() method

http://www.programering.com/a/MDM0AjMwATY.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for this. Using addEntity() method try to map result with object and may be that's why I was getting error column not found. I have removed addEntity and tried to do same thing previously.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("call getUserData(:firstName,:lastName)")      
                //.addEntity(User.class)
                .setParameter("firstName", firstName)
                .setParameter("lastName", lastName);

        userList = query.list();

        System.out.println(userList);
        //output is [[Ljava.lang.Object;@2a9a3bb0]
        //It will return List of array of object. So need to iterate according.

        for(int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {

            Object[] obj =  (Object[]) userList.get(i);

            for(int j=0; j<obj.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(obj[j]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking, the problem is that you're expecting "List of User" as the return value from the Stored procedure.

However, you're not selecting "id" field in the SELECT query. How can Hibernate build a "User" class without this field, which is a primary key.

Change your SP to include this field as below -

set queryString = concat(queryString, 'select u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName from user u where 1=1');

The change is working for me. Try it out !

Thanks.

Comment: If I am adding **id** then its showing error on other field. But if I am adding * in select query then its working fine. So I am not able to understand what is actual problem here.